Why can't Mathematica determine the sign of the square root of a positive expression?
I am trying to determine whether an expression is positive, but I am new to Mathematica and ran into some unexpected behavior. I simplified the expression to better understand what was going on, but I am still at a loss. In the three code lines below I am checking if the square root of an expression is positive, given that the expression is positive. I would have expected that Mathematica will always evaluate this condition to be true, but it does not.

The first code line below evaluates to True as expected.
Once I add the variable c (second line), mathematica can no longer determine whether the condition is true.
What is even more confusing, in the third line, I add the assumption that c is an integer between 0 and 2, which basically would imply that c is 1 and thus the third and the first line should correspond. But neither here mathematica can determine if the condition is true.

Simplify[Sqrt[(1 + (1/beta - f2/sigma))^2 - 4*(1/beta + f1/sigma)] > 0, {(1 + (1/beta - f2/sigma))^2 - 4*(1/beta + f1/sigma) > 0}]

Simplify[Sqrt[(1 + (1/beta - c*f2/sigma))^2 - 4*(1/beta + f1/sigma)] > 0, {(1 + (1/beta - c*f2/sigma))^2 - 4*(1/beta + f1/sigma) > 0, Element[c, Reals]}]

Simplify[Sqrt[(1 + (1/beta - c*f2/sigma))^2 - 4*(1/beta + f1/sigma)] > 0, {(1 + (1/beta - c*f2/sigma))^2 - 4*(1/beta + f1/sigma) > 0, c > 0, c < 2, Element[c, Integers]}]

What am I missing?

Assuming[0<c<2&&Element[c,Integers],Simplify[c]] returns c and Assuming[0<c<2&&Element[c,Integers],FullSimplify[c]] returns c and Assuming[0<c<2&&Element[c,Integers],Refine[c]] returns c There is a line under Possible Issues in the Refine help page that says "Expressions appearing algebraically in inequality assumptions are assumed to be real" which may relate to this. I do not know whether your Element[c,Integers] overrides this or not.

If $c$ is a complex number, there is no guarantee that $c^2$ is positive. That is true for other variables beta, sigma, etc. So you need to add more assumption for these parameters.

@A.Kato What you say about c is correct but I do no think it has any impact on OP code. OP code is simply saying that if x>0 than Sqrt[x]>0. Now you can substitute any expression for x at it is always true. But if you substitute expression form OP code Mathematica is not able to simplify it.

There are limits to complexity built into solvers and simplifiers. In this case, there is a way for the user to adjust: We have to raise "AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" to at least 5:
With[{simpopts = SystemOptions["SimplificationOptions"]},
 WithCleanup[
  SetSystemOptions[
   "SimplificationOptions" -> {"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 
      5}];
  Simplify[
   Sqrt[(1 + (1/beta - c*f2/sigma))^2 - 4*(1/beta + f1/sigma)] > 0
   , {
    (1 + (1/beta - c*f2/sigma))^2 - 4*(1/beta + f1/sigma) > 0,
    Element[c, Reals]
    }],
  SetSystemOptions[simpopts] (* reset *)
  ]]

(*  True  *) 


That was what I thought too... that there were too many variables but could not figure out how to overcome it.

@azerbajdzan Yeah, sometimes the limits can be set through documented options and sometimes through system options. Sometimes I can't find a way, either.

This is amazing, thanks! I am going to accept the answer, but could you first briefly explain what this does and are there limitations to when I can use this, i.e. am I going to break something else when using this? Also, does the same work for other commands such as reduce or similar?

@Maggie Thanks. The code raises "AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" to 5; and then it resets the option back to its default limit. All I know about the option is what you can infer from its name and from the fact that the default limit is 4 and you had 5 variables in your assumption. My guess is that raising it allows Mathematica to work harder and longer on simplifying things. That might lead to it wasting time. I doubt the option affects Reduce, which doesn't use assumptions. It may affect commands that use assumptions, like Refine, and will affect those calling Simplify.

Note that WithCleanup[code, reset], executes the reset even if the code was aborted (cmd-dot on a Mac). So the system option is only temporarily changed. By its name, I don't think this option would break anything if it is raised, unless something that would have stopped in a second ends up running for days. If you lower it below 4, then some things might not work, since they were tested with the default setting.

Got it, thanks!
